# Using Array.sort to sort anagrams in a String array

Tags: java

I would like to sort an array based on their group of anagrams.

For Example:

```
[anew, sale, wane, ales, ascent, seal, wean, leas, secant]
```

Should output:

```
[anew, wane, wean, ales, leas, sale, seal, ascent, secant]
```

Or it could output anagrams on any order as long as they are grouped together.

So I tried doing this:

```
Arrays.sort(array, (s1, s2) -> {
   if (s1.length < s2.length)
        return -1;
    else if (s1.length > s2.length)
        return 1;
    else
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
   });
```

But I got this:

```
[secant, leas, wean, seal, ascent, ales, wane, sale, anew]
```

I know the issue is in the comparator but I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: your comparator doesn't seem right to me. if two given elements are equal then by definition your comparator should return `0` which i don't see in your code at the moment.

Comment: @Aominè I tried that and got the same result

Comment: I am also sure of the functionality of the checkAnagrams method because I had thoroughly tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm cannot possibly work, because sorting is achieved by comparing elements locally. To sort by number of anagrams you need to remember what strings are anagrams of one another. This is not a decision, which is possible by comparing two elements without context. You need to identify and collect the anagrams first. Then you can construct the result list.

Comment: What if I were to just sort them if they are anagrams without needing to sort by how many they are?

Comment: Dosen't make a difference, it is still not a local decision. You need to keep the anagrams together while getting the other strings cluster as anagrams. This cannot be done by sorting.

Comment: @Stefan you are wrong. This would be a boolean sort and that is possible to sort arrays of boolean.

Comment: @Antoniossss any idea on how to do it with Arrays.sort ?

Comment: @Antoniossss How do you try to reduce the problem to sorting booleans?

Answer (score 0):

```
package sandbox;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class AnagramSort {
    private static final String[] DATA = { "anew", "sale", "wane", "ales", "ascent", "seal", "wean", "leas", "secant" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList(DATA);

        System.out.println(data);
        data.sort(AnagramSort::isAnagram);
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public static int isAnagram(String a, String b) {
        char[] s1 = a.toCharArray();
        char[] s2 = b.toCharArray();
        if (s1.length < s2.length)
            return -1;
        else if (s1.length > s2.length)
            return 1;

        Arrays.sort(s1);
        Arrays.sort(s2);
        return Arrays.compare(s1,s2);

    }
}
```

Results in:

> [sale, ales, seal, leas, anew, wane, wean, ascent, secant]

That's probably close to what you need with some tuning done to the isAnagram method (I wrote a crude quick version for this test, and I am not checking is one string is an anagram contained fully inside another larger string).

Comment: Thanks but if I didn't care about the order of the anagrams just as long as they are grouped together can I simply do it with the Arrays.sort with a comparator?

Comment: First part of that isAnagram checks if they are the same size, if not they are sorted by size, the next part checks if they are an anagram and sorts on that.  You can do whatever you need it to do.

Comment: Could you please clarify on how I could write that in a comparator in Arrays.sort?

Comment: You comparator has to be aware of what an anagram is otherwise the only thing you can sort on is string size and if it goes before or after another string.  The method I have above (isAnagram) is actually a comparator method used by sort() method (the lambda makes it all happen).

Comment: Arrays.sort(DATA, AnagramSort::isAnagram);  will do the sort for you using that method as comparator, I converted it to List so it could be easily displayed with System.out and to use List::sort which pretty much works like Arrays::sort.